# How to solve angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I was using [this](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/MEAN-stack-authentication) as a starter for my project after going through [this MEAN stack tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/user-authentication-mean-stack/). However, when I started using the unminified copy (/app_client/main.js) provided instead of minified Angular app(/app_client/app.min.js) by changing the script file in /app_client/index.js, I started to get this error:

```
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]
```

After a few hours of googling, I found this could be due to injection But checked all controllers and they were minification safe as they used proper DI(dependency Injection) using

```
MyCtrl.$inject = ['$http']; //hence, making minification safe
```

I still can't resolve it. Please enlighten me what I could have missed.

PS: You need to add

```
app.listen(PORT_NUMBER);
```

in the app.js file at root for the project to be visible.

Comment: Use [strict mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection) with unminified app to eliminate the problem. This will guarantee that the same problem won't appear again.

Comment: I tried ng-strict-di, But it gave me no warning or errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a stupid question. On further researching, I found out that this is exactly what gulp/grunt like task-runners are made for.
Thank you all.